# Trim first 9 letters using awk, sed

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have following data in file, i need to only keep first 9 character of file and | tee it to another file

```
03755432101JONPORT,
037554321031979123120800000000000000000000000000000000
0375543210413855
03755432105JEEY
03755432111P63
03755432133100620120000008156GR1
```

should look like

```
037554321
037554321
037554321
037554321
037554321
037554321
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For such a simple task, use `cut`:

```
cut -b1-9
```

If your data contains Unicode, you might need `-c` instead of `-b`.

Comment: `cut -c1-9` is probably more accurate here.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.\{9\}\).*/\1/' input_file
```

#### Using `gawk`:

```
gawk '{temp = gensub(/(.{9}).*/,"\\1", "g"); print temp}' input_file
```

However, for such simple needs use `cut` as @choroba has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `grep` command :

```
grep -o "^.\{9\}" FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use:-

```
cut -c10-
```

Comment: He want to keep the first 9, not the characters following them.

Comment: as @lhf mentioned, for keeping the first 9 letters-
cut -c1-9
would work fine.